# ViewController loads only if the initial storyboard (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm using MVCarouselCollectionView framework for an image gallery
View a photo gallery of only works if it is the storyboard of the initial
Project Link: [link download code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw6D0bj13hdaMXpMS1F4RFd5T2s/view?usp=sharing)

If I put the gallery view to be the initial, it will work. however if I put her to be the second view and use the following / push will not work

Gallery code

```
import UIKit
import MVCarouselCollectionView
import QuartzCore
import Alamofire

class GaleriaDeFotosViewController: UIViewController, MVCarouselCollectionViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet var collectionView : MVCarouselCollectionView!


var imagePaths : [String] = []

// Closure to load local images with UIImage.named
var imageLoader: ((imageView: UIImageView, imagePath : String, completion: (newImage: Bool) -> ()) -> ()) = {
    (imageView: UIImageView, imagePath : String, completion: (newImage: Bool) -> ()) in

    imageView.image = UIImage(named:imagePath)
    completion(newImage: imageView.image != nil)
}


@IBAction func BtnCarregar(sender: AnyObject) {
    configureCollectionView()
    carregaFotoModo1()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureCollectionView()
    carregaFotoModo1()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func configureCollectionView() {

    view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = imagePaths.count

    collectionView.selectDelegate = self
    collectionView.imagePaths = imagePaths
    collectionView.commonImageLoader = self.imageLoader
    collectionView.maximumZoom = 2.0
    collectionView.pagingEnabled = true
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
// MARK:  MVCarouselCollectionViewDelegate
func carousel(carousel: MVCarouselCollectionView, didSelectCellAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Do something with cell selection
}
func carousel(carousel: MVCarouselCollectionView, didScrollToCellAtIndex cellIndex : NSInteger) {

    // Page changed, can use this to update page control
    self.pageControl.currentPage = cellIndex
}
func addAsChildViewController(parentViewController : UIViewController, attachToView parentView: UIView)
{

    parentViewController.addChildViewController(self)
    self.didMoveToParentViewController(parentViewController)
    parentView.addSubview(self.view)
    self.autoLayout(parentView)
}

func autoLayout(parentView: UIView) {

    self.matchLayoutAttribute(.Left, parentView:parentView)
    self.matchLayoutAttribute(.Right, parentView:parentView)
    self.matchLayoutAttribute(.Bottom, parentView:parentView)
    self.matchLayoutAttribute(.Top, parentView:parentView)
}
func matchLayoutAttribute(attribute : NSLayoutAttribute, parentView: UIView) {

    parentView.addConstraint(
        NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.view, attribute:attribute, relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem:parentView, attribute:attribute, multiplier:1.0, constant:0))
}
// MARK: FullScreenViewControllerDelegate
func willCloseWithSelectedIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.collectionView.resetZoom()
    self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated:false)
}

func carregaFotoModo1()
{

    self.imageLoader = imageViewLoadFromPath

    self.imagePaths = [
                            "http://li.zoocdn.com/bb3d7c42506f563c1174828c97522728a87cfae8_645_430.jpg",
                            "http://li.zoocdn.com/162fd32ce15911cba3dcdf27a8a37238708991bc_645_430.jpg",
                            "http://li.zoocdn.com/9e17e58963944f4a6695c56561f1bd4ee0803cba_645_430.jpg",
                            "http://li.zoocdn.com/ffdbb7c884427a1d599f052cae4f205bf63373cf_645_430.jpg",
                        ]
    println(self.imagePaths)
    self.configureCollectionView()
}
}
```